# Separating html file in apps script

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script

I have an apps script file where I want to separate my html and css. Given we can't create .css files in apps script, I have create a file 'mainmenucss.html' and put my css in a style tag, and using the include function (see below) to add that file in, but none of my styling is showing when I do that.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <?!= include('mainmenucss.html') ?> 
  </head>
```

code.gs

```
function doGet(request) {
   return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('mainmenu')
      .evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}
```

mainmenucss.html

```
    <style>

      /*-- Text you have "X" emails left --*/
      div {
        display: block;
      }

      body {
        font: normal 10pt Arial, sans-serif;
      }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this modification?

I think that in your script, an error might occur at `return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename).getContent();`. Because HtmlTemplate has no method of `getContent()`. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename).getContent();
```

#### To:

```
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename).evaluate().getContent();
```

or

#### To:

```
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
```

#### Note:

- If above modification didn't resolve your issue, can you provide the script of `mainmenucss.html`?
- If you are using Web Apps, when you modified the script, please redeploy Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script reflects to Web Apps.

#### References:

- [createTemplateFromFile()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createTemplateFromFile(String))
- [createHtmlOutputFromFile()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createhtmloutputfromfilefilename)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work either. the stylesheet is just a standard stylesheet in <style></style> tags, I know it works as I can paste it into the main html file and it works fine.

Comment: ps @Tanaike I have updated my code above. Does that help? Thanks!

Comment: @Luke Byrne Thank you for replying and update your question. I apologize for the inconvenience. When I saw your updated question, I noticed that your script is not correct. When you want to use `createHtmlOutputFromFile`, please modify `return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).evaluate.getContent();` to `return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();`. And after you modified the script, please redeploy Web Apps as new version, and run the script again.

Comment: thanks again but that didn't work either. I again modified code and included some css.

Comment: Also the <?!= include('mainmenucss'); ?> shows up in my prompt when I run this web app inside sheets, that might be the problem so thought I'd let you know.

Comment: @Luke Byrne Thank you for replying and updating it. If you are actually using only the scripts in your question on a GAS project, I think that your scripts work and the CSS can be reflected to HTML. So could you please confirm that Web Apps is deployed as new version. And for example, how about modifying `mainmenucss.html` to only `<style>/*-- Text you have "X" emails left --*/ div {display: block;} body {font: normal 10pt Arial, sans-serif;}</style>`? And also, if you are using other scripts, how about creating new GAS project and put only the scripts in your question and testing it?

Comment: Thanks! Yes I can confirm it's deployed as a new version, and I changed the CSS to that but still no change, the css does not show in the html

Comment: @Luke Byrne Thank you for replying. I would like to replicate your issue and confirm your current situation. So can you share the Spreadsheet including the container-bound script, if you are using the script on Spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I will share a copy tomorrow if that's okay - I need to clear personal data on it.